# Did Robb Stark find out Roose Bolton had released Jaime to King's Landing?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, Roose Bolton captured Jaime and sent him back to King's Landing against Robb Stark's will.

Not long after Robb Stark was murdered at the Red Wedding. I am wondering: before his death, did Robb Stark find out Roose had freed Jaime?

Comment: Assuming he did not object to having Roose Bolton at the Red Wedding (before the carnage began), I assume he never knew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely not. Robb sent his men after Jaime with the fastest horses and his order was to bring Jaime back after Catelyn freed him, and this objective didn't change. Roose Bolton releasing Jaime was already a beginning of his treachery and his conspiracy with the Lannisters. Had Robb known this, he certainly wouldn't be celebrating the Red Wedding with him.